# COBOL: Can a GDG file descriptor (FD) reference multiple generations?

Tags: cobol

I have a program which reads a GDG file and moves data to working storage. I am interested to know if it can be made to repeat this process for multiple generations of the GDG using a reference to the file definition. Perhaps there is a way to use subscripts on the file definition? My thought is there must be a method to move different file definitions into a reference variable from which to access the files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Code Sample based on suggested, `setenv` solution

```
FILE-CONTROL.
SELECT DATAIN        ASSIGN TO UT-S-DATAIN.

DATA DIVISION.
FILE-SECTION.
FD  DATAIN                         
BLOCK CONTAINS 0 RECORDS       
RECORD CONTAINS 133 CHARACTERS 
LABEL RECORDS ARE STANDARD     
DATA RECORD IS DATA-REC.       
01  DATA-REC   PIC X(133).         

WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.   
01  ENV-VARS.                                             
02  ENV-NAME        PIC  X(9).                        
02  ENV-VALUE       PIC  X(100).                      
02  ENV-OVERWRITE   PIC  S9(8) COMPUTATIONAL VALUE 1.

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
MOVE Z"DATAIN" TO ENV-NAME                                   
MOVE Z"DSN(PROGRAMMER.TEST.GDGFILE(-1)),SHR" TO ENV-VALUE 
MOVE 1 TO ENV-OVERWRITE                                      
CALL "setenv" USING ENV-NAME ENV-VALUE ENV-OVERWRITE.
```

### Notes

1. Pay special attention when moving DSN value to ENV-VALUE. On my first swing I left out the closing parentheses, most likely because of JCL muscle memory.
2. Be sure to empty out your DD statement in JCL/Step.

Answer (score 2):

In mainframe COBOL, the `FD` refers to a `SELECT` which refers to a `DD` statement attached to the `EXEC PGM` statement for your program in the invoking JCL.  The `DD` statement may refer to one or many GDGs.  This is determined at compile time.

What I think you are asking for is dynamic allocation of a file at *runtime*.  There are a couple of ways to accomplish that, one is BPXWDYN.

```
   Identification Division.
   Program-ID.    SOMETEST.
   Environment Division.
   Input-Output Section.
   File-Control.
       Select MY-FILE             Assign SYSUT1A.
   Data Division.
   File Section.
   FD  MY-FILE
       Record 80
       Block 0
       Recording F.
   01  MY-FILE-REC        PIC X(080).
   Working-Storage Section.
   01  CONSTANTS.
       05  BPXWDYN-PGM             PIC X(008) VALUE 'BPXWDYN '.
       05  ALCT-LIT-PROC           PIC X(035)
               VALUE 'ALLOC FI(SYSUT1A) SHR MSG(WTP) DSN('.
       05  FREE-LIT-PROC           PIC X(016)
               VALUE 'FREE FI(SYSUT1A)'.
       05  A-QUOTE                 PIC X(001) VALUE "'".

   01  WORK-AREAS.
       05  WS-DSN                  PIC X(044) VALUE 'MY.GDG.BASE'.
       05  WS-GDG-NB               PIC 999    VALUE ZEROS.
       05  BPXWDYN-PARM.
           10                      PIC S9(004) COMP-5 VALUE +100.
           10  BPXWDYN-PARM-TXT    PIC X(100).


   Procedure Division.
  *    Construct the allocation string for BPXWDYN.
       MOVE SPACES TO BPXWDYN-PARM-TXT
       STRING
           ALCT-LIT-PROC
             DELIMITED SIZE
           WS-DSN
             DELIMITED SPACE
           '(-'
             DELIMITED SIZE
           WS-GDG-NB
             DELIMITED SIZE
           ')'
             DELIMITED SIZE
         INTO
           BPXWDYN-PARM-TXT
       END-STRING

       CALL BPXWDYN-PGM USING
           BPXWDYN-PARM
       END-CALL

       IF RETURN-CODE = 0
           CONTINUE
       ELSE
           [error handling]
       END-IF

       [file I/O with MY-FILE]

       MOVE SPACES TO BPXWDYN-PARM-TXT
       MOVE FREE-LIT-PROC TO BPXWDYN-PARM-TXT

       CALL BPXWDYN-PGM USING
           BPXWDYN-PARM
       END-CALL

       IF RETURN-CODE = 0
           CONTINUE
       ELSE
           [error handling]
       END-IF

       GOBACK.
```

This is just freehand, so there may be a syntax error, but I hope I've made the idea clear.

There is another technique, using the C RTL function `setenv`, documented by IBM [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21046577).  It looks like it might be simpler but I've never done it that way.

Comment: Initial research exposed me to this, uh, can I call it utility? (BPXWDYN) and when I tried to compile w/ this solution I received a link error 

`IEW2456E 9207 SYMBOL BPXWDYN UNRESOLVED.  MEMBER COULD NOT BE INCLUDED FROM THE DESIGNATED CALL LIBRARY. `

I thought I would explore the other option you suggested before calling my systems people and found the `setenv` method worked out perfectly. I'm not sure if this is allowed (please correct me if I'm wrong), but I'll mark this correct for getting me to a solution and add the code sample that worked for me as another answer.

Comment: @TechSparrow if you like, you could accept your own answer instead of mine, this is completely acceptable on Stack Overflow.  Regarding the link error, if you call BPXWDYN dynamically that should eliminate the IEW2456E message.