# Dynamic file creation in COBOL/JCL

Tags: db2, cobol, jcl, cics

I have an requirement, Where I have to read DB2 table and create multiple output file, one for each program name in the table. We don't know how many unique program name in the table. My job will run every 4 hrs. So for eg: my first run may have 10 program name and I will have to create 10 output file and second run may 20 program name and 20 output files.

I'm looking for a dynamic way to create DD name and file name in the JCL as well in my COBOL program. So I don't want to define 20 or max DD statement in my JCL, as this 20 can be 50,60....

Please help me with the possibilities.

Comment: Do you really have to do this in a CICS environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is [BPXWDYN](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=services-bpxwdyn-text-interface-dynamic-allocation-dynamic-output), which is callable from COBOL, et. al.  A COBOL example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50138638/cobol-can-a-gdg-file-descriptor-fd-reference-multiple-generations/50140458#50140458).

Comment: BPXWDYN worked well for creating dynamic file. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a canned service that will do what you want.  You can explore how to call a program that would do the dynamic allocation for you.  Here is a [starting point](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=functions-dynalloc-allocate-data-set) in the z/OS documentation.

This example is a 'C' program that will execute a dynamic allocation based on values from the caller.

It's not turnkey but is worth exploring.

Comment: Thanks.I will give a try and post the update here.

Comment: I just learned, there is no C compiler in my company. I will have to try other options.

Comment: Look at BPXWDYN which was recommended by @cschneid looks more like what you are looking for.